# Spark - dataset.persist() : how to check if dataset persisted?

Tags: java, apache-spark

How to check, that the dataset was persisted ?

```
dataset.persist();
```

Comment: you can also check `dataset.queryExecution`. A cached dataset with have an `InMemoryRelation` and an `InMemoryTableScan`

Comment: @philantrovert thanks, but not fully covered. And how about if I used StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER() ?

Answer (score 0):

1 To see if cached, try to use `sparkSession.catalog.isCached("viewName")`.
2 To tell if there's data cached in disk, see it in Spark Web UI's *Storage* tab.